# For loop to increase font-size until fill body height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, for-loop

I'm having problems with for-loop. My objective is to pick one element ".synopsis p" (there are more) and use it to increment its font-size by 1px each loop to make the element wider. When the width of the element ".synopsis p" matches the width of the document.body it stops and calls changeCSS() function to appends on body the css to change all the elements with ".synopsis p".

I created an codepen to ease the process https://codepen.io/alexandrebuxo/pen/eYvBJGJ

Could someone help me?
Thanks

```js
    $(window).on("load", function () {
      $(".modal2 svg").fadeOut(700);
      $(".modal2").delay(500).fadeOut(1000);});
      

    var body_height = $("body").innerHeight();

    var sinopsis_size = parseInt($(".synopsis p").css("font-size"));
    var production_size = parseInt($(".production p").css("font-size"));

    function changeCSS() {
      $(document.body).append("<style>.synopsis{font-size:" + sinopsis_size + "px;}</style>");
    }

    for (var i = 0; parseInt($(".synopsis p").innerWidth()) < body_height; i++) {
      $(".synopsis p").css("font-size", (parseInt($(".synopsis p").css("font-size")) + 1) + "px");
      if ($(".synopsis p").innerWidth() == body_height - 1) {
        changeCSS();
      }
    }
```

```css
:root {
      --animation-time: 15s;
      --animation-time-2: 15s;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: Ottoatta;
      src: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2171/2773/files/OTTOATTACTYPE.ttf?v=1620751934");
      font-style: normal;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: Obviously;
      src: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2171/2773/files/Obviously-Light.ttf?v=1620808950");
      font-style: normal;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: Obviously Extended;
      src: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2171/2773/files/Obviously-Extended-LightItalic.ttf?v=1620825483");
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: 200;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: Obviously Extended;
      src: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2171/2773/files/Obviously-Extended-Light.ttf?v=1620825483");
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 200;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: Obviously Extended;
      src: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2171/2773/files/Obviously-Extended-RegularItalic.ttf?v=1620825757");
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      color: #fff;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 200%;
    }
    #page {
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      display: flex;
    }
    #page-image {
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      /*background-color: #000;*/
      background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2171/2773/files/fundo3.jpg?v=1621377390");
      background-attachment: local;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      display: flex;
    }
    .pane {
      min-width: 100vw;
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    /*.pane:nth-child(2) {
    }
    .pane:nth-child(3) {
    }
    .pane:nth-child(4) {
    }
    .pane:last-child {
    }*/
    .text {
      font-family: "Obviously";
      font-size: 0.5em;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .text2 {
      font-family: "Obviously Extended";
      font-size: 0.4em;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .italic {
      font-style: italic;
    }
    .title,
    .subtitle {
      text-shadow: 0 0 15px #ffeb3b;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .title {
      font-size: 7.5em;
    }
    .subtitle {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
    .title-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 100vw;
      padding: 0 5vw;
    }
    .title,
    .subtitle {
      font-family: "Ottoatta";
    }
    .left {
      text-align: left;
    }
    .center {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .right {
      text-align: right;
    }
    .text-box {
      width: 50vw;
      white-space: normal;
    }
    .margin-left {
      margin-left: 15vw;
    }
    .modal2 {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: flex;
      z-index: 1000;
      background-color: #fff;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .modal2 svg {
      filter: invert(1);
    }
    .vertical-text {
      transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
      left: -0px;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 100vh;
      height: 30vw;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-size: 100px;
      color: #ffffff;
      z-index: 1;
      font-family: "Ottoatta";
      text-shadow: 0 0 15px #ffeb3b;
    }
    .vertical-text2 {
      left: -10px;
    }
    .slide-right.delay1 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right1;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right1;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right1;
      animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right1;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .slide-right.delay2 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right2;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right2;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right2;
      animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right2;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .slide-right.delay3 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right3;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right3;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right3;
      animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right3;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .vertical-text2.slide-right.delay1 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right4;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right4;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right4;
      animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right4;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .vertical-text2.slide-right.delay2 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right5;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right5;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right5;
      animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right5;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .vertical-text2.slide-right.delay3 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right6;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right6;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right6;
      animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right6;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .vertical-text2.slide-right.delay4 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right7;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right7;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right7;
      animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right7;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .video {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    .relative {
      position: relative;
    }
    .text-block2 {
      bottom: 10vh;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .e400 {
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    .e200 {
      font-weight: 200;
    } /*
    .production {
      font-size: 4.5em;
    }
    .manual {
      font-size: 4.5em;
    }*/
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right1 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right1 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right1 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right1 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right2 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right2 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right2 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right2 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right3 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right3 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right3 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right3 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right4 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -300%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right4 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -300%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right4 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -300%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right4 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -300%;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right5 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right5 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right5 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right5 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right6 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right6 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right6 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right6 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right7 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 300%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right7 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 300%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right7 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 300%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right7 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 300%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
  <head>
    <title>AEON</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>

  <div class="modal2">
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="38"
      height="38"
      viewBox="0 0 38 38"
    >
      <defs>
        <linearGradient x1="8.042%" y1="0%" x2="65.682%" y2="23.865%" id="a">
          <stop stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0" offset="0%" />
          <stop stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity=".631" offset="63.146%" />
          <stop stop-color="#fff" offset="100%" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g transform="translate(1 1)">
          <path
            d="M36 18c0-9.94-8.06-18-18-18"
            id="Oval-2"
            stroke="url(#a)"
            stroke-width="2"
          >
            <animateTransform
              attributeName="transform"
              type="rotate"
              from="0 18 18"
              to="360 18 18"
              dur="0.9s"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
            />
          </path>
          <circle fill="#fff" cx="36" cy="18" r="1">
            <animateTransform
              attributeName="transform"
              type="rotate"
              from="0 18 18"
              to="360 18 18"
              dur="0.9s"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
            />
          </circle>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="page-image">
      <div class="pane">
        <div class="vertical-text test slide-right delay1 synopsis">
          <p class="">Synopsis—</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vertical-text slide-right delay2 synopsis">
          <p class="">Synopsis—</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vertical-text slide-right delay3 synopsis">
          <p class="">Synopsis—</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-box margin-left">
          <p class="text">
            In a fictional universe in which we become aware that we are
            destined to live our lives once more, and innumerable times more, we
            speculate about the truth that resides in the possibility of the
            infinite, making use of repetition as the great propeller of
            questions and answers.
          </p>
          <p class="text">
            This cyclically infinite realm portrays the consciousness of Aeon,
            an entity that was never born nor has ever died, who therefore
            comprises a collection of memories represented by fragments,
            suspended in eternal repetition.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loop to increase font-size to fill body height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67688950/for-loop-to-increase-font-size-to-fill-body-height)

Comment: @zcoop98 Yes it did! :) Thanks